# My old CPU, mainboard works perfect but the brand Ryzen 5 4600G and MSi B550 Tomahawk board is not working

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, power-supply

My old power supply, old CPU and old mainboard works perfect

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Fc1bB-j4TKo

But the B550 Tomahawk board, brand new Ryzen 5 4600G is not working

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Dv7_ReTqLsM

I tried removing the battery out of the Tomahawk board for a few minutes, and tried flashing BIOS to the latest available from MSi official website,

But it still is not working you can see the Ryzen CPU fan working for maybe 0.2 seconds and stops

Any advices?

Comment: not sure what relevance the old board working has ... anyway, the causes of what you show in the second video can be many. Bad power connection, bad CPU, badly installed CPU, broken motherboard, badly seated RAM .... the list goes on - do you have the CPU power connected (4 or 8 pin or maybe more) up near the CPU and backplane?

Comment: If the old board is working that means the power supply is working perfectly.  And yes, it is 8 pin CPU power and properly connected

Comment: ahh, so that first video shows that the power supply works - got it. So, now you need to determine if you have a bad cpu, or the CPU is badly installed (perhaps some bent pins?) or the motherboard is faulty (though, you somehow updated the BIOS, or at least you say you did), or your RAM is faulty or poorly seated, or the myriad of other things that can cause such an issue

Comment: @JaromandaX CPU is brand new out of box, and the RAM is properly placed because I saw that the 2nd and 4th slot must be occupied first,

Comment: seated/placed not the same, try a single stick in each slot, one at a time ... AMD CPU's aren't immune to being Dead on Arrival (DoA), you can't see if there's bent pins when you installed it unless you remove the CPU and inspect it (and the socket for that matter) - motherboards can also be DoA - the CPU fan looks like it's attached to SYS_FAN3 - perhaps the motherboard refuses to boot without a fan conencted to CPU_FAN1 ... as I said, there's literally hundreds of causes for those symptoms

Comment: You say you upgraded the BIOS ... exactly how did you do that

Comment: @JaromandaX On YouTube there are excellent 5 minute clips of how to update the BIOS to the latest, without the CPU ( in other words how to update the BIOS of the mainboard even if you have no CPU )

Comment: indeed there are, but the method varies between manufacturers and boards - I just wanted to know what you did, not what others did on other boards. Also, youtube videos are never a better source of information than the manual that came with the motherboard, detailing what you should be doing .... e.g. did you name the file on the USB stick **MSI.ROM**? How long did the LED blink after pressing "Flash BIOS"? Did you wait for it to stop blinking?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I specifically looked up for clips regarding MSi mainboards, I unzipped it and renamed into MSI.ROM all capital letters bro and the file system was FAT32 not NTFS

Comment: and the LED blinked for several minutes ... anyway, since that seemed to have worked, the other possibilities I've mentioned more than once are still at play ... badly SEATED RAM, badly installed CPU (bent pins for example), DoA CPU, the fact that the CPU fan is connected to the wrong place (unlikely, but perhaps some motherboards do protect you from powering on without a CPU fan), damage to the motherboard after you updated BIOS (unless the board behaved exactly the same before you did so) ... I could go on, but there's too many possible mistakes

Comment: Personally, I think it's the CPU. I've seen many youtube videos about dead (brand new) 4xxx series CPUs.